# useEffect keeps being entered after fetching data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have my `useEffect` in the `Profile` component like this:

```
const [mappedPosts, setMappedPosts] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchMedia();

  if (userPosts) {
    console.log("This keeps entering!");
    const mapped = userPosts.map((post, index) => (
      <View key={index}>
        <Text>{post.title}</Text>
      </View>
    ));

    setMappedPosts(mapped);
  }
}, []);
```

And my `Profile` component returns,

```
return mappedPosts ? (
  <View>
    {mappedPosts}
  </View>
) : (
  <Spinner />
);
```

My problem is the following:

The `Spinner` component is rendered when I have:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchMedia();

      if (userPosts) {...};

        setMappedPosts(mapped);
      }
    }, []);
```

or

```
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchMedia();

      if (userPosts) {...};

        setMappedPosts(mapped);
      }
    }, [mappedPosts]);
```

And the appropriate data is rendered when I have:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchMedia();

      if (userPosts) {...};

        setMappedPosts(mapped);
      }
    }, [userPosts]);
```

or

```
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchMedia();

      if (userPosts) {...};

        setMappedPosts(mapped);
      }
    });
```

The problem with the last two is that the line `console.log("This keeps entering!");` is printed over and over again, indicating that the component keeps rerendering. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The below variation keeps rerendering the component as well:

```
 const [mappedPosts, setMappedPosts] = useState(null);

 useEffect(() => {
      fetchMedia();

      if (userPosts && mappedPosts === null) {
           console.log("entered!");
           const mapped = userPosts.map((post, index) => (
                <View key={index}>
                     <Text>{post.title}</Text>
                </View>
           ));

           setMappedPosts(mapped);
      }
 }, [userPosts]);

 console.log("am I being re-rendered?");

 return mappedPosts ? (
      <View>
           {mappedPosts}
      </View>
 ) : (
      <Spinner />
 );
```

I know this because `console.log("am I being re-rendered?");` keeps printing nonstop... even though the data is already rendered and displayed appropriately on the screen (I'm using react-native).

The `Profile` component gets `userPosts` from the redux store:

```
const Profile = ({
  navigation,
  posts: { userPosts, loading },
  auth: { isAuthenticated },
  fetchMedia,
  checkAuth
}) => {

    const [mappedPosts, setMappedPosts] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
       fetchMedia();
.......
```

---

## Edit:

The `fetchMedia`:

```
export const fetchMedia = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_MEDIA
  });

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://${GATEWAY}:5000/api/posts/user`);

    dispatch({
      type: MEDIA_SUCCESS,
      payload: response.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: MEDIA_FAIL
    });
  }
};
```

The reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  userPosts: null,
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case FETCH_MEDIA:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };

    case MEDIA_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        userPosts: payload,
        loading: false
      };

    case MEDIA_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: what's `userPosts`?

Comment: The `fetchMedia()` is an async function that pulls data from Mongodb via my backend API and stores it in the redux state. So `userPosts` is "connected" from the store to this component. I'll edit the OP

Comment: So `fetchMedia` dispatches an action that will cause redux middleware to load data and `userPosts` comes from props?

Comment: Do you have a loop of `am I being re-rendered?` and `entered!`? Can you show more of out `userPosts` is get and set?

Comment: @HMR Yes, I'll add the actions

Comment: @Federkun Sure, one sec, I'll edit the OP. Yes, there's a loop nonstop.

Comment: I've made the changes to the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out. The problem was that fetchMedia was being called every single time the component changed. So once `userPosts` were fetched.. they were fetched again. And again. And again. That's why the component kept rerendering. Here's the change I made:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (userPosts) {
    console.log("entered!");
    const mapped = userPosts.map((post, index) => (
      <View key={index}>
        <Text>{post.title}</Text>
      </View>
    ));

    setMappedPosts(mapped);
  } else {
    fetchMedia();
  }
}, [userPosts]);
```

Comment: You can do `useEffect(fetchMedia,[])` and fetchMedia will only be called on mount and dismount but it would be better to indroduce a `requested` prop so your component(s) only dispatch the request action if data has not been requested yet (see my answer).

Comment: I think your answer probably will work since there is only set of `userPosts` and only one component with the `useEffect(...fetchMeda...)` on page so you won't dispatch fetching media multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer will probably work because data will only be fetched once and `userPost` never changes reference.

Usually putting REST data in state is a bit more complicated than what you do. If you need data then the container will select the data something like this:

```
const NOT_REQUESTED = {requested:false}
state => state.data.someData || NOT_REQUESTED
```

Then the component can request the data **if it was not requested**.

```
useEffect(()=>requested || fetchData(),[requested])
```

The reducer will set requested and loading as a response to requested action:

```
{
  ...state,
  data: {
    ...state.data,
    someData: { requested: true, loading: true },
  },
};
```

Now when your component will re render but `fetchData` is not called because requested is true.

When request succeeds the reducer can write the result on data success action:

```
{
  ...state,
  data: {
    ...state.data,
    someData: {
      ...state.data.someData,
      loading: false,
      data: action.data,
    },
  },
};
```

This is not with server side filtering, sorting, stale data or error handling but I hope you get the idea.

If you want component(s) to dispatch actions to load data then your containers/selectors need to produce props that indicate if the data has been requested or not.

Comment: I figured it out.. feel very stupid. I posted the answer. Thanks for your help and time.